# Transform not working in GeomectryDrawing in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<Style x:Key="ICON" TargetType="Rectangle">
<Setter Property="Fill">
  <Setter.Value>
    <DrawingBrush TileMode="None">
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
          <GeometryDrawing Brush="Gray" Geometry="F1M19.5625,0.999954C29.8144,0.999954 38.125,9.31053 38.125,19.5625 38.125,29.8142 29.8143,38.1249 19.5625,38.1249 9.31073,38.1249 1,29.8142 1,19.5625 1,9.31053 9.31064,0.999954 19.5625,0.999954z">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
              <Pen DashCap="Square" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Round" MiterLimit="10" StartLineCap="Flat" Thickness="2">
                <Pen.Brush>
                  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.849422,0.849423" StartPoint="0.150577,0.150578">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF657783" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.146"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF2C4758" Offset="1"/>
                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Pen.Brush>
                <Pen.DashStyle>
                  <DashStyle/>
                </Pen.DashStyle>
              </Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
          </GeometryDrawing>

          <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Gray" Geometry="F1 M0,25 L25,50, 50,25 25,0z">
              <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen DashCap="Triangle" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Bevel" MiterLimit="10" StartLineCap="Flat" Thickness="5">
                  <Pen.Brush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                      <GradientStop Color="#FF657783" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#FF2C4758" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Pen.Brush>
                  <Pen.DashStyle>
                    <DashStyle/>
                  </Pen.DashStyle>
                </Pen>
              </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing>

            <DrawingGroup.Transform>
              <TranslateTransform X="0.2" Y="0.2" />
            </DrawingGroup.Transform>
          </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
      </DrawingBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The inner icon should dominate the outer icon but here, its happening the reverse. My initial guess is that transform is not working but on further observation, I feel that the code is written correctly. Can anyone point out whats the mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working, but you should adjust it properties a little. So the code should look like this. Also I've added code for scaling romb.

```
<DrawingGroup.Transform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <TranslateTransform X="12" Y="12" />
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75" />
    </TransformGroup>
</DrawingGroup.Transform>
```